# Function evaluation with default parameters that refer to each other

Tags: r, evaluation

Why for

```
f <- function( y=5, x = y) x + y

f() # 10
```

evaluates to 10 but

```
 eval(body(f),formals(f))
```

does not?

It checks the promise, see value 5 for varable y then search value for variable x and doesn't evaluate further to use 5. Why?

Comment: R just doesn't allow you to fake promises in environments (or environment-like lists) the way they work during function calls. `formals()` gives you a list with a numeric value and a symbol. There's no mechanism in `eval()` to double expand the symbol in to a value then evaluate the expression. So i guess the "why" is that evaluating in environments that contain symbols is not the the same as allowing a function to lazily evaluate parameter promises.

Comment: So for x it finds quote(y)?

Comment: Yep. `str(formals(f))` shows that the value for `x` is a symbol.

Comment: Maybe another way to think about this is that when actually calling the function f, R creates a local (temporary) environment in which to evaluate the promises. But `eval` doesn't do this; it just evaluates the expression in an existing environment, by default the global environment.

Comment: More on argument evaluation in the R language definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation